# Fragment onStop called from other Activity than it's parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle, fragmentmanager

Activity A starts Activity B with startActivityForResult().
Activity B adds a fragment F from it's onCreate().

Activity A is no longer visible and onStop() is called. This also calls onStop() for fragment F. At the same time, Activity B which is a parent Activity to F does not call onStop().

Why is onStop() called on fragment F from an Activity other than it's parent?
There are no other operations on FragmentManager other than adding fragment F.
I am using support libs 24.2.1, AppCompatActivity and support FragmentManager.

Comment: You can add finish() after startActivity() method inside startActivityForResult() to destory Activity A. But I am curious on what makes you think that onStop() in Activity A calls onStop() in Fragment inside Activity B. What happens to Activity B when this happens?

Comment: I do not want to finish the Activity A, while displaying Activity B. I've put a log line in fragment F onStop() and a breakpoint to it. By using debugger and analyzing the stack trace here, I can see that this log line inside fragment's onStop() is being called by Activity A instance. When this happens, Activity B and fragment F are being displayed and are in started state.